# How to paste through vba with same options as Ctrl-v (no formatting)?

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I need to paste some text from a mail direct into my excel, when i copy it and ctrl-v, it works fine.
But i cant find a paste formula that works like that.

When i paste it as values it messes the whole sheet up.

```
Range("BC1").Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
```

I have tried this without any luck and a `xlpastevalues`...

My texts needs to be pasted intro one columns as texts does ( i have another macro to covert it to a defined table ).

Does it make sense? if not i can post some pictures.

Comment: Not clear .. Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastespecialoperation and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype

Comment: Try `ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML"` ... OR... `ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text"`

Comment: If you want to use `ctrl-v` option, have a look at `MSForms.DataObject`. This will paste whatever you have in your clipboard

Comment: @NareshBhople Format:="HTML" worked like a charm :)

It paste in one column, so I can easily convert it later. 

Perfect!
Thanks :)

You can put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML"` ... OR... `ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text"`

I tried to paste(with right click) text from mail to Excel and got following shortcut menu.

[image]

This was the 'paste' menu which I used to get when I used to copy from Crome. So, I recorded macro selecting "Match Destination Formatting" option.
[image]

In VBA I got

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
    False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
```

Then I recorded macro selecting Text Option in Paste Special menu
[image]

and in VBA I got

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
    False
```

Comment: Greate idear, was playing around with matchsource but didnt think about recording the paste part :)

But the HTML did the trick :)
The TEXT format messed it up as tried earlier :)